# Unknown segment in NewRelic Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic, radiant

I'm trying to track down the cause of my site to locking up using NewRelic to examine the slowest transaction (the site is running Radiant CMS, and the slow transaction in this case is SiteController#show_page). In one of the transactions wherein the site becomes unresponsive, there are two calls to "(unknown)" that take approximately 77 seconds. Has anyone run into something like this before?

screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiq7Q.png

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the New Relic Ruby agent encountering a tracing error that prevents the agent from recording the proper name on that segment of the transaction. I would recommend checking your New Relic agent logs for ERROR or WARN lines that could point to this. By default, these logs will be located in your application's `log/` directory. If the agent logs are unclear, feel free to open a support ticket at support.newrelic.com.